# Android Fast and Precise Canvas Graphing?

Tags: android, canvas, graph, handler, ondraw

I am developing an android application which gets graph values over tcp and draws the graph realtime and continuously.The application has to draw 100 pixels/values per second, finishing a 1000 pixel width graph in 10 seconds.

I am developing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 Tablet.

Below is the main activity code.I just pasted necessary parts.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MyGraph graph;
private Handler mHandler;
private Handler mHandler2;
private boolean running;

public static int counter=1;
private int limit=1000;

private class MyGraph extends View {

  private Paint       paintecg     = new Paint();
  private Paint       paintdel  = new Paint();
  private Canvas      canvas     = new Canvas();

  private Bitmap cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000,800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    private float nextX;        //next point in x axis
    private float lastX=0;
    private float nextY;        // next point in y axis
    private float lastY=150;

    public MyGraph(Context context){
        super(context);

        paintecg.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paintecg.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paintecg.setAntiAlias(true); paintecg.setStrokeWidth(2f);

        paintdel.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paintdel.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (cache != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(cache, 0, 0, paintecg);

    }

    public void drawNext() {
        canvas = new Canvas(cache);

        nextX=lastX+1;
            //adding new points to the graph
            canvas.drawLine(lastX,valuearray_ecg[counter-1],nextX,valuearray_ecg[counter], paintecg);
            //emptying next 25 pixels
            canvas.drawRect(nextX, 0, nextX+25, 800, paintdel);

            lastX=nextX;

               if (nextX<limit) {
                    counter++;
                 }
               else {
                    counter=1;
                    lastX=0;
                 }
             postInvalidate();
          }

 }
```

}

This is the handler created inside oncreate() method :

```
    LinearLayout graphView=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_graph);
graph = new MyGraph(this);
        mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                graph.drawNext();
             if (running)
                    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 10);
                return true;
            }
        });
graphView.addView(graph);
```

Graph is drawed inside a layout in main.xml

This way, when i set handler to 20 ms and my x-axis steps to 2 pixels, it draws 1000 pix in around 15 seconds.Weird thing is, if i lock and unlock the device while app is running, timing becomes normal and draws 1000 pixels in 10 seconds.

when i set handler's delay to 10 miliseconds and x-axis steps to 1 pixel, at first it draws 1000 pixels in 25+ seconds.After locking and unlocking it drops 20- seconds.

I see i'm probably doing it wrong.My question is, is there any way to draw a graph that fast using android's native canvas drawing? Or what is the best way to handle an app like this?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple things.

- do not recreate canvas each time. It's not needed.
- to erase old data use drawColor instead of drawRect. You'll need to set clipRect first.
- do not invalidate everything, invalidate only the area you have changed (that is - same clipRect)
- disable drawing cache. Basically because you handle the cache in your own code. See comments to answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805640/stackoverflowerror-when-calling-getdrawingcache-from-ondraw).

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying these now, but i have a couple more questions :

For not creating canvas each time, should i use canvas.setBitmap or something else?

I tried using a 100x800 bitmap with cliprect for my active drawing area, but this area's coordinates must change constantly to continue drawing more.I can't seem to do that.

And for drawing cache, the "cache" in my code is just my bitmap, are there any more caching options i enabled?

Comment: Yes, use `setBitmap`. For changing cliprect use `clipRect(left, top, right, bottom, Op.REPLACE)`. And yes, "cache" means your bitmap here, so you should disable android's internal drawing cache with `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

To add to @aragaer's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948136/383414):

Here's some useful info - the most important part for you would be I recommend you use `SurfaceView` instead of a normal `Canvas`.

I would read up on game dev for Android - you will find lots of useful high-speed drawing info there.